# Bold Times New Roman

Tags: bold, times, roman

I'm using Times New Roman in my thesis. But bold mode doesn't work. Here is code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}[2013/05/05]
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{SOME TEXT}
\end{document}
```

How I can use bold style?

Comment: I know of no `ftm` font family. Try `\usepackage{tgtermes}` or `\usepackage{newtxtext}` instead of that dubious `\renewcommand`.

Comment: I've tried both variants, but don't get bold font.

Comment: Can you add the log file you get from compiling the example?

Comment: @egreg Probably Edvard has used `\renewcommand` in the MWE after have read the [LaTeX2e Font Selection](http://latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf) guide. Anyway, to set the Times font family according to that guide, he had to indicate `ptm` and not `ftm`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using XeLaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\begin{document}
Привет мир! \textbf{Привет мир!}

Hello World! \textbf{Hello World!}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: @AndrewCashner True. I also like TG Termes better than Times New Roman, because it's open source, but OP asked for Times New Roman.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you get rid of the `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}` part and use

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

Instead.

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}

Your text without bold.  \textbf{Your text in bold}
\end{document}
```

Produces the following output:

[image]

**EDIT**

According to the new information of your MWE and the comments by Philippe Goutet, you should be able to use the times fonts in bold like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}


\begin{document}

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
Your text without bold.  \textbf{Your text in bold}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't help. How I can use bold style?

Comment: Oh sorry now I see that problem in my code in line \usepackage[russian]{babel}. So MWE actually looks like this:

    `\documentclass[a4paper]{report}`

    `\usepackage[russian]{babel}`

    `\usepackage{mathptmx}`

    `\begin{document}`

 `Without bold.  \textbf{Text in bold}`

    `\end{document}`

Comment: @Edvard: add a `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont` just before the english text you want to be in Times. As it is, since Times is not available in the T2A encoding, it gets substituted into Computer Modern.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest just putting

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

in your preamble. (That is, just change `ftm` to `ptm`.) That makes your example work for me.

Comment: @most-respondents: except that `ptm` is `adobe times roman`, which is _not_ `times new roman` as you see on your widnoze screen.  (tbh, i can't see a difference, but there have been posts on c.t.t, in the past, about people checking the pdf's loaded fonts to be sure the author is a “good boy”.)